# From a numpy matrix, find the inner-list containing the most of a single value, with one constraint

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix that looks like:

```
matrix = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
           1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
           0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

edit: in response to request for the matrix output, how about turning to array?
`m = np.array(matrix)`

I'm trying to find the inner list containing the most 1s or 0s, *with one constraint*.

The constraint is that, when searching for the most 1s or 0s in the inner-lists, the inner-list is segmented. For example, each inner-list should be segmented at the 12th index.
So when searching for the longest 1s or 0s, it may be in the first inner-list's first segment(before 12th index), or it may be in the last segment(after 12th index).

Is there an easier numpy-way to get this done?

Output format is flexible as long as it denotes the inner list index, and `True` for "before 12th index" or `False` for "after 12th index".

Here's an example:
*these example answers correspond to the example matrix above*
Most ONES: `1`, `True` (index of inner list's position, `True` denotes that it is before 12th index).
Most ZEROES: `2`, `False` (list index, `False` because after index)

This may be a bit confusing--please let me know if I can clarify something for you.

edit: to clarify, not searching for longest sequence. Searching for segment with the most appearances of the given value.

Comment: Can you provide output for the given matrix?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa can you work with an array? I updated the post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC for find 1's you can use the below code, for 0's replace 1 with 0:

```
a = np.array(matrix)
#taking values only till 12th index
Before_12_index = (a[:,:13]==1).sum(1)
#taking values only after 12th index
After_12_index = (a[:,13:]==1).sum(1)

#condition for checking whether they have max number of 1 before or after 12th index
cond_1 = (Before_12_index>After_12_index).reshape(-1,1)

cond_1
array([[False],
       [ True],
       [ True]])
```

Comment: What does the `1` signify in `.sum(1)` ?

Comment: `.sum(1)` == `.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @Casper `.sum(1)` represents sum across rows.